# Iterating through a list in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Spinning my wheels here!

- I’m working with a 20K node network I’d like to put into NetLogo (ultimate goal is a spin on the model library's Simple Viral Marketing model) (got this working great!)
- I’ve precooked the specific nodes I’d like to work in Netlogo using Python.  For example, here is a list of top 20 nodes in my graph by betweenness centrality:
  set nodelist ["73647" "52658" "78667" "97632" "22987" "101425" "97788" "15439" "46269" "45942" "46016" "95372" "83259" "22757" "91392" "101355" "12915" "905" "95940" "88071"]
- These nodes represent the top 20 nodes in my graph sorted descending
  by betweenness centrality (around 25 minutes in Python Networkx to
  get this)

So, what I want to do is:

1. For an arbitrary number called budget (n,0-19), take the first n
   node_ids from nodelist (turtles own variable called node_id)
2. Lookup the corresponding Who that matches the node_id
3. Ask a turtle by Who number to do something, e.g., [set adopt? =
   true]

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you actually tried the Simple Viral Marketing model with 20000 nodes? The network extension may be just as fast as Python's Networkx in calculating betweenness and then you can simply create the agentset with `max-n-of` instead of working with lists of `who` numbers

Comment: Unfortunately, I found the NetLogo network extension orders of magnitude slower than Networkx in calculating betweeness scores.  25 minutes with NetworkX, gave up on NetLogo calculating this after 4 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can walk down a list in many different ways.
One is to use the "foreach" command.
Another is to use an explicit loop over the index number, starting at zero.

Here's a demo of both of them.
"setup" runs setup
"go" once finds the items and makes them big and shows their labels
"go" again makes them small again.

```
globals [ NUMTURTLES BUDGET NODELISTSIZE nodelist ]
turtles-own [ adopt?  node_id]

to setup
  clear-all
  let rseed random 999999;
  print (word "random seed being used for this run is : " rseed );
  random-seed rseed;
  
  ;; globals or sliders, low values to see what's going on
  set BUDGET random  5;  ( 0 to 19 )
  set NUMTURTLES    30;
  set NODELISTSIZE  10; ;; something bigger than BUDGET!
  
  print (word "BUDGET = " BUDGET );
  
  
  create-turtles NUMTURTLES 
      [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor  
        set adopt? false 
        set node_id random 999999
       ]
  
  set nodelist [];
  ask N-of NODELISTSIZE turtles [ set nodelist lput node_id nodelist ]
  show nodelist;
  
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if ( ticks = 0)
  [    ;; option #1: make a sublist and use the "foreach" command to walk down it
       let worklist sublist nodelist 0 BUDGET
       show worklist
       foreach worklist [ 
             a -> print (word "next item in worklist " a)
         ask one-of turtles with [ node_id = a ] [ set adopt? true set size 3 set label a]
          ]
  ]
  
  ;; undo the above a different way
  
  if ( ticks = 1 )  
  [   ;; option #2:  use effectively for i = 0 to BUDGET to process list item i
      ;; do NOT forget the "set i ( i + 1 )" or this will run forever! 
      let i 0
      repeat BUDGET [
      let b item i nodelist
      print (word "item " i " which is " b " will be undone");
      ask one-of turtles with [ node_id = b ] [ set adopt? false set size 1 ]
      set i ( i + 1 )
      ]
    
  ]
  tick
end
```